# Show that $T$ is injective, find the range $R(T)$ of $T$, and find the inverse operator $T^{−1}: R(T) → C[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C[0, 1]$ be the linear space of all continuous functions on the interval $[0, 1]$ equipped with the norm $||f|| = max_{0≤x≤1}|f(x)|$. Define the operator $$T : C[0, 1] → C[0, 1]$$ by
$$T f(x) = \int^ x_0f(s) ds$$.
Show that $T$ is injective, find the range $R(T)$ of $T$, and find the inverse operator
$T^{−1}: R(T) → C[0, 1]$. Is $T^{−1}$ a bounded operator in the sup norm?

Proof:
Injectivity:
$Tf(x_1)=Tf(x_2)\Rightarrow \int^ {x_1}_0f(s) ds=\int^ {x_2}_0f(s) ds\Rightarrow (\int^ {x_1}_0f(s) ds)^{'}=(\int^ {x_2}_0f(s) ds)^{'} \Rightarrow f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ By FTC (?) I am uncertain about this.

Alternatively, we can show there is always a solution for $y=Tf(x)$ so $T$ is invertible and thus injective. Could this work?

Range:
$R(T)=\{y: y=\int^ x_0f(s) ds\, x\in [0,1]\}$. Is this enough or do we have to find an exact solution $[0,1]$? If so maybe we could use the fact that $|Tf|\leq ||f||(x-0)$, and $||Tf||\leq ||f||$?

Since $\int^ x_0f(s) ds$ is an invertible function, by FTC we can define $T^{-1}=f(x)$. Could this direction be correct? I am not sure what comes next.

Since T is bounded then $T^{-1}$ is bounded? what do they mean about the sup norm?

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that $T$ is injective you start with $Tf=Tg$ which means $\int_0^{x} f(t)dt=\int_0^{x} g(t)dt$ for all $x$. By differentiation this gives $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ so $f=g$.

Note that $Tf$ is a $C^{1}$ function vanishing at $0$ for any $f \in C[0,1]$.  Let $M$ be the class of all $C^{1}$ functions vanishing at $0$. Every function in $M$ can be writen as $Tg$: Take $g=f'$. Hence, the range is exactly $M$ .
The inverse is not continuous: The inverse operator is just the derivative: $T^{-1}g=g'$ for all $g \in M$. Let $f_n(x)=x^{n}$. Then $Tf(x)=\frac {x^{n+1}} {n+1}$ and $Tf_n \to 0$ in the norm of $C[0,1]$. However, $f_n$ does not tend to $0$ in the sup norm.

Comment: For this part "vanishing at 0" meaning $Tf(0)=0$ for all $f$ right?

Comment: Yes, $Tf(0)=0$ for all $f$. @Mihai.Mehe